# Error thrown when trying to set SES to publish events to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, localstack

I'm trying to run set-identity-notification-topic on SES in my localstack and an error gets thrown. Any workaround or a solution is kindly appreciated.

I have verified my email address with SES on localstack. However I get an error when trying to run,

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4579 ses set-identity-notification-topic --identity myname@domain.com --notification-type Bounce --sns-topic arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:LOCAL_ses_responses --debug
```

stacktrace:

......
......

> 2019-08-07 17:04:39,539 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.ses.SetIdentityNotificationTopic: calling handler  2019-08-07 17:04:39,540 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth. 2019-08-07 17:04:39,540 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest: POST /     content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8 host:localhost:4579 x-amz-date:20190807T070439Z     content-type;host;x-amz-date e19fa7707096ec4f34644c4d08291160421d771325cc9d8b696cb376f4f39749 2019-08-07 17:04:39,540 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20190807T070439Z 20190807/us-east-1/ses/aws4_request 4922714082f96a39b9065b91093231d793cdec8af0da19698616090b17501d28 2019-08-07 17:04:39,540 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature: 06afe49a26eb61b6420bc726da1eb79b4e0a0011fe4a246ec2e9541bed2b0c3c 2019-08-07 17:04:39,540 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: http://localhost:4579/, headers={'Content-Type': b'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'User-Agent': b'aws-cli/1.16.210 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/18.5.0 botocore/1.12.200', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20190807T070439Z', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAII5V24FP6F2TGDUQ/20190807/us-east-1/ses/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=06afe49a26eb61b6420bc726da1eb79b4e0a0011fe4a246ec2e9541bed2b0c3c', 'Content-Length': '194'}> 2019-08-07 17:04:39,541 - MainThread - urllib3.util.retry - DEBUG - Converted retries value: False -> Retry(total=False, connect=None, read=None, redirect=0, status=None) 2019-08-07 17:04:39,541 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG
- Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:4579 2019-08-07 17:04:39,550 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG
- http://localhost:4579 "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 2019-08-07 17:04:39,551 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Length': '290', 'Server': 'Werkzeug/0.15.5 Python/3.6.8', 'Date': 'Wed, 07 Aug 2019 07:04:39 GMT'} 2019-08-07 17:04:39,551 - MainThread - botocore.parsers
- DEBUG - Response body: b'\n500 Internal Server Error\n

## Internal Server Error

\n

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

\n' 2019-08-07 17:04:39,551 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main() Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/danuka.aluthage/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 432, in _parse_xml_string_to_dom
    parser.feed(xml_string)   File "", line None xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 54     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:     Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/danuka.aluthage/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 207, in main
    return command_table[parsed_args.command](remaining, parsed_args)   File "/Users/danuka.aluthage/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 348, in **call**

.....
.....

Unable to parse response (syntax error: line 1, column 54), invalid XML received:
b'\n500 Internal Server Error\n

## Internal Server Error

\n

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

\n'

Comment: why are you saying SES when you're overriding SES endpoint to localhost:4579. Does it work directly when you don't use localhost:4579 ? Whats configured in localhost:4579 , does it configured correct to proxy traffic further ?

Comment: hi James, This is not in the real aws environment. I have set up localstack in my machine. the SES service runs on port 4579 in localhost. Without localhost:4579 commands will execute against actual aws, which I haven't tried due to not having permission yet.